# Chained Hash Table Error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, linked-list, hashtable, hashcode

In this assignment for my Python Data Structures course, I'm combining concepts of hash tables and linked lists to create a chained hash table. I'm struggling with setting the items in the chained hash table. I would appreciate any guidance and direction towards finding a solution. I will provide my code, output and error message below:

**Python Code**

```
class SLLH():
    
    class DataNode():
        
        def __init__(self, key, val):
            if not isinstance(val,str) and not isinstance(val,int):
                raise Exception("data must be either interger or string")
            if not isinstance(key,str) and not isinstance(key,int):                
                raise Exception("key type must be either string or integer")
                
            self.key = key
            self.val = val
            
            self.next = None
                
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.key)+",|"+str(self.val)+"|"
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.sz = 0
    
    def append(self, key, val):
        node = self.DataNode(key,val)
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.sz += 1
        
    
    def remove_at(self, idx):
        if idx < 0:
            raise Exception("index cannot be negative for chain LL.")
        
        cur = self.head
        cur_idx = 0
        
        if(idx == 0 and self.head):
            node = self.head
            self.head = self.head.next
            self.sz -=1
            
            return str(node.val)
        
        while(cur and cur_idx < idx -1):
            cur = cur.next
            cur_idx +=1
            
        if(not cur or not cur.next):
            raise Exception("Index out of bounds for chain LL.")
        
        node = cur.next
        cur.next = cur.next.next
        self.sz -=1
        
        return node
    
    
    def remove(self, key):
        to_be_removed = []
        for i in range(self.sz):
            if self.getitem_at(i).key==key:                
                to_be_removed.append(i)
                break
                
        if to_be_removed: 
            self.remove_at(to_be_removed[0])
        else:
            raise Exception(f"An entry with key {key} doesn't exist")
                
    def getitem_at(self, idx):
        cur = self.head        
        cur_idx = 0
        
        while(cur and cur_idx < idx):
            cur = cur.next
            cur_idx+=1
        
        if(cur):
            return cur
        
        raise Exception(f"Inedex {idx} out of bounds for list of length {cur_idx+1}")

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        
        curr = self.head
        
        while curr.key != key:
            curr = curr.next
            
        return curr.val
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        str_rep = ""
        arrow_str = "--> "
        
        str_rep += arrow_str
        
        cur = self.head
        while(cur):
            str_rep+=str(cur)+" "
            str_rep += arrow_str
            cur = cur.next
        str_rep += "NULL\n"
        
        return str_rep

        

class ChainedHashTable():
    
    def to_ascii_sum(self, key_str):
        return sum(list(map(ord, key_str)))
    
    def sum_digits(self, key_int):
        sum = 0
        for digit in str(key_int):
             sum += int(digit)
        return sum
    
    def data_to_int(self, key):
        if (type(key)) == str:
            return self.to_ascii_sum(key)
        elif (type(key)==int):
            return self.sum_digits(key)
        else:
            raise Exception("key type must be either string or integer")
            
    def mod_hashFunc(self, key):
        return self.data_to_int(key)%self.slot_count
    
    def __init__(self, slot_count):
        assert slot_count > 0, Exception("table size must be greater than zero")
        self.slot_count = slot_count
        self.table = [SLLH() for _ in range(self.slot_count)]
        self.hashfunc = self.mod_hashFunc
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        slot_idx = self.hashfunc(key)
        ll = self.table[slot_idx]
        return ll[key]
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        slot_idx = self.hashfunc(key)
        linkedList = self.table[slot_idx]
        linkedList[key] = val
        
        

    def remove(self, key):
        slot_idx = self.hashfunc(key)
        self.table[slot_idx].remove(key)
        
    def __str__(self):
        str_rep = ""
        
        for slot in range(self.slot_count):
            str_rep += str(self.table[slot])
            
        return str_rep
```

**Code For Testing**

```
ht = ChainedHashTable(7)
print(ht)  
ht[0] = 10
ht[5] = 50
ht[9] = 90
ht[4] = 40
print(ht)
```

**Output and TypeError**

```
        --> NULL
        --> NULL
        --> NULL
        --> NULL
        --> NULL
        --> NULL
        --> NULL
    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ht[0] = 10
      2 ht[5] = 50
      3 ht[9] = 90

Input In [1], in ChainedHashTable.__setitem__(self, key, val)
    144 slot_idx = self.hashfunc(key)
    145 linkedList = self.table[slot_idx]
--> 146 linkedList[key].append(key,value)

Input In [1], in SLLH.__getitem__(self, key)
     83 def __getitem__(self, key):
     85     curr = self.head
---> 87     while curr.key != key:
     88         curr = curr.next
     90     return curr.val

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: If key is an integer, `sum_digits` is called, which is currently an empty function that always returns None.

Comment: You have not implemented `sum_digit`, thus the function returns `None` for `self.data_to_int(key)`. You cannot do `None % int`.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out. I've updated my code with a complete sum_digits function however I'm still receiving an error I don't know how to solve. I have updated code and error messages

Comment: I get a different error running your example - `ht[0] = 10 ... in __setitem__ ... linkedList[key] = val ... TypeError: 'SLLH' object does not support item assignment`. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Note: when an `SLLH` instance is made its *`.head`* is None. Nowhere in your code do you append to an SLLH instance so its head is always None

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, an implementation of `sum_digits` was missing which you have now added.

In the new error trace we see this code:

```
    linkedList = self.table[slot_idx]
    linkedList[key].append(key,value)
```

In the actual code you presented, this code looks different:

```
    linkedList = self.table[slot_idx]
    linkedList[key] = value
```

Either way, it is wrong. `linkedlist` is just that: a linked list. You cannot access `linkedlist[key]`. You should just do:

```
    linkedList = self.table[slot_idx]
    linkedList.append(key,value)
```

With that change the main code will run without error.